# Why does ScrollView scroll to top and then to the bottom when using ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN?

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollview

The most common solution to scroll a ScrollView to bottom is the following code:

```
scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN));
```

OR

```
scrollView.postDelayed(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN), 100);
```

This does the work albeit with an issue that is, the page first scrolls to the top and then scrolls to the bottom as if it has refreshed. I do not want that to happen. I have also tried the `scrollTo()`, `scrollBy()`, `smoothScrollTo()`, `smoothScrollBy()` functions and a few other unconventional solutions but they all scroll from top to bottom, if at all they scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out myself. I had used the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` attribute for a few views on the page and they were redundant. I removed them and the problem has been solved.